# Change php.ini value issue

Tags: php, server, configuration

I want to change the **php.ini** this option **sendmail_path** to this below:

```
sendmail_path /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i
```

PHP ini file is loaded from: **/opt/php72/etc/php.ini**.

The problem is that this value can be changed only from **Master** value, the **Local** value is still displayed as following:

```
sendmail_path   /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f admin.example.com
```

Any ideas where should I look for to change this value, so it applies for both Local and Master values? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have figured it out by myself. The problem was that this value was set in the Apache configuration file. So, I have changed it to **php_admin_value sendmail_path "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i"**, restarted the server and now everything works well. The issue is resolved. Thank you.